# If statement only uses last data set of xml PHP

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

My If statement only works if the conditions are met in the last data set of the XML data. If the conditions are met before the last entry it does not recognize.

Here is the XML data

```
<PaymentsByMonthYear xmlns="server" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:schemaLocation="http://server.fseconomy.net/static/datafeed_payments.xsd" total="4">
<Payment>
  <Id>51180698</Id>
  <Date>2015/02/02 15:23:27</Date>
  <To>Solo</To>
  <From>Jon</From>
  <Amount>1000.00</Amount>
</Payment>
<Payment>
  <Id>51182828</Id>
  <Date>2015/02/02 16:57:44</Date>
  <To>Solo</To>
  <From>lj440</From>
  <Amount>100.00</Amount>
</Payment>
<Payment>
  <Id>51192472</Id>
  <Date>2015/02/02 21:28:25</Date>
  <To>SoloBanner</To>
  <From>lj440</From>
  <Amount>5000.00</Amount>
  <Reason>Group payment</Reason>
</Payment>
<Payment>
  <Id>51234023</Id>
  <Date>2015/02/04 06:00:55</Date>
  <To>Bob</To>
  <From>SoloBanner</From>
  <Amount>5100.00</Amount>
</PaymentsByMonthYear>
```

Here is the Code I have, it works as long as the last Payment meets the If otherwise it returns "no"

```
<?php
  //Define Username
  $user = "lj440";

  //Connect to Server
  $link1 = "data.xml";
  $xml1 = simplexml_load_file($link1) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

  //Gather Fields
  foreach($xml1->children() as $info1)
   {
   $from = $info1->From;
   $date = $info1->Date;
   $amount = $info1->Amount;
   }

  //Create If Statement
  if (($user == $from) AND (strtotime($date) > strtotime("1 month ago")) AND ($amount >= "5000.00"))
{
 echo "yes";
}

else
{
echo "no";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach($xml1->children() as $info1)
   {
    $from = $info1->From;
    $date = $info1->Date;
    $amount = $info1->Amount;
   }
```

Do you see any `if` statement there? Nope. That loop just runs and runs and those variables get the value of last element. Since your if statement comes ***after*** this loop, it only sees the last element and does what it does.

Solution? Move your `if` ***inside*** the loop.

Comment: I added the 'if' statement to the loop as best I know how but now get the response 'nonono'. Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `else` if you only want to echo when there is a match